# Issue with onTouch method in my android app

Tags: android

I am Working on a android project where i am stuck with removing a view on `onTouch` method when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is triggered.

My code is as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    View point = null;
        switch (event.getAction()){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                if(touch_circle(x,y)) {
                    point = new Circle_draw(getApplicationContext(),x,y);
                    layout.addView(point);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }
    return true;
}
```

and more code related to this are as follows

```
public class Circle_draw extends View{

    int width;
    int height;
    public Circle_draw(Context context,int width,int height) {
        super(context);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(width,height,5,paint);
    }

}
```

how can i remove this view from my activity class?? using `Action_UP`

and the Whole Code for this activity is as follows:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

RelativeLayout layout;
int height;
int width;
View control;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVariables();
    layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    layout.addView(control);
    control.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
public void setVariables(){
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.controllerLayout);
    height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    control = new ThumbController(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    View point = null;
        switch (event.getAction()){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                if(touch_circle(x,y)) {
                    point = new Circle_draw(getApplicationContext(),x,y);
                    layout.addView(point);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
    return true;
}

public boolean touch_circle(int x,int y){
    boolean touch = false;
    x=x-width;
    y=y-height;
    int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2));
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"distance=" + String.valueOf(distance),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(distance<=120){
        touch = true;
    }
    return touch;
}


public class ThumbController extends View{

    public ThumbController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int radius = 120;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        width = width-75;
        height = height-150;
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(width, height, radius, paint);
    }
}

public class Circle_draw extends View{

    int width;
    int height;
    public Circle_draw(Context context,int width,int height) {
        super(context);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(width,height,5,paint);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: just use `ViewGroup#removeView()` method

Comment: i am not using any viewgroup.. can you post any example for me to refer?

Comment: yes, you are using `ViewGroup`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to add your custom view to any parent `ViewGroup`, read carefully `ViewGroup` documentation

Comment: tried not working :(

Comment: `ViewGroup#removeView` is definitely working

Comment: wait let me post the whole code for you then you let me know ... coz i m not using any ViewGroup

Comment: Yes you are right .. i solved it :) thanks got my mistake